# git clone not working

Tags: git

So I'm new to linux and all.

I've been trying to configure my nvim recently.
Then suddenly the plugins didnt get installed (failed at cloning) and thought it might be plugin manager ([packer](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim)) problem, So was tryna reinstall it and now when I enter

```
$ git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim\
 ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim
```

it just takes forever and then shows

```
 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim/': SSL connection timeout
```

Any clues is much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clone via ssh protocol, notice that "-v" flag which may help to clarify details

```
git clone -v git@github.com:wbthomason/packer.nvim.git
```

Or just turn off ssl verification and try to clone

```
git config --global http.sslverify "false"
```

Comment: I've tried turning ssl veification off before but still the same problem.
And in the ssh protocol it gives me a permission denied (public key).